# Selective Backup in Apple Mail Email Client

Tags: mail.app, backup, email, gmail, productivity

I have an IMAP Gmail account which I have logged in through Apple Mail email client on my Mac book pro. I have sorted out some important emails and made a separate folder for those emails. Is it possible to backup only that email folder and not all the emails along with them? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being it a unique request I had to search a lot for the solution of this query and I landed up on this blog: http://applemailbackupapp.blogspot.com/2016/08/apple-mail-backup-application.html

I hope this must be helpful. Thanks

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: Thanks for the solution George. I found Mail Backup X, got the trial version of this application. This is the only thing that I needed. Apart from backing up tool has got a mail viewer and I am also able to select the emails i want to backup. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

In mail.app, you can select a folder and from the main menu choose ‘Mailbox > Export Mailbox’, select a location for the export file and click ‘choose’.  Mail exports the mailbox as an .mbox package.

See also this page: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19174?locale=en_US